# How to select text with same style token applied in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I want to select all text with same style token applied on notepad++. My goal is to remove all similarly styled words and sentences.

[image: Notepad++ Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5 highlighting styles in Notepad++ serve for your visual navigation and currently they have no further use for processing. But you can manually add some text to them once you finished highlighting. That will enable possibility of automated processing.

You can do this:

1. Find a character not used in your file. E.g. `#`. (Or in worst case, take for example this one: `¤`)
2. Surround your highlighted phrases with that character, e.g. `Lorem` → `¤Lorem¤`.
3. Using regex replace like `¤.*?¤` (replace with: empty) you can remove all marked sentences.

---

As an alternative, you can go without style tokens, clearing text immediately as you find it:

1. Mark `Lorem` (or entire phrase) as selection.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show find/replace dialog (what you marked is already inside).
3. Clear content of **Replace With** box (if any).
4. Click **Replace all**.

---

If you expect some more comfortable way, then I'd agree with you it is not implemented.

Comment: It seems like that feature is not implemented, but can hope for the same. Thank you for the tips.

Comment: @lalthomas – I updated the answer not to forget that viewpoint. So now it should be complete enough so you perhaps could accept it.